# c# rules about: a mod b, while a is bigger than b

Tags: c#

I was examining a code about operator overloading, and I saw an interesting way of use of % to convert seconds to minutes if second variable is bigger than 59.

It seems while `a<b` (both int) `a%b` returns a, I havent read a rule about this before, I wanna learn why it returns a, is it about they are declared as integers, are there any more rules about %?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what the % operator does? It is just the remander after you do a divsion. If b is bigger than a and you do a / b, you are going to get 0 with a remainder of a.

Comment: To keep it simple % = Modulo = **Remainder**. If `a<b` then the `a/b` = `0`  + `a` the **Remainder**. if `a > b` then `a/b` = `SomeConstant` + **Remainder**. `%` removes the `SomeConstant` and keeps the **Remainder**

Comment: when a is bigger than b or equals, yes I know what % does, lets say if a =32 and b=60, it should return 20, maybe coz of they are ints, it cant return 20 and it returns a, thats for sure

Comment: @Lloyd well, yeah. :P Thanks

Comment: @Sezar Wrong. 32 % 60 = 32. Maybe you should brush up your maths knowledge...

Comment: How does `32 % 60` equal 20? Can´t imagine any operator which results 20, neither `%` nor any other.

Comment: 32/60=0.533333... right? and the remainder of it goes as 20... am I wrong?

Comment: @Sezar **INTEGER** division, thus `32 / 60 == 0`! If you do a float division, there will be no reminder. See my answer - I added a part about your seconds/minutes example.

Comment: what if they were floats? :)

Comment: @Sezar The same thing applies for: `-101.4 % 100.3 == -1,10000000000001` due to rounding issues. See my reply, especially the other equation I've provided. This will clear things up.

Comment: i checked thanks and thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for any `a` and any `b`:

**a / b = (SomeConstant * b) + RemainderOfb***

So if `a = 2` and `b = 5` means `a < b` then:

> How many SomeConstant do you need to multiply b with, in order to get close to a? And once you get close, what is your remainder?

so if

`a / b  = (5 * 0) + 2`

Means **Remainder = 2** out of 5.

Then: `a % b` means the Remainder with respect to `b`, which is = 2.

And if `a = 3` and `b = 2` means `a > b` then:

> If you remove all the "b"s from a, what is the Remainder? You can do
>   it the easy way: Subtract "a" from "b" till you can't subtract
>   anymore. Or:

`a / b = SomeConstant * a (which is how many "a"s did you subtract) + Remainder`

Substitute:

`a / b = (1 * 2) + 1`

Means **Remainder = 1** out of the 2

Then `a % b` equals the Remainder with respect to `a`, which is = 1

Comment: @Sezar glad we were able to help :) feel free to accept / upvote answers

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the modulo operator. The modulo operation `a % b` returns the remainder `z` in the division

```
a / b = x, remainder z
```

In other words, it returns `y` in this equation:

```
x * b + y = a
```

*The second equation also shows why this works for fractional numbers too.**

Thus, the following examples (not complete) are true:

```
-5 % 4 = -1
-4 % 4 = 0
-3 % 4 = -3
 ...
 1 % 4 = 1
 2 % 4 = 2
 3 % 4 = 3
 4 % 4 = 0
 5 % 4 = 1
 ...
 101.4 % 100.3 = 1.1
```

---

In your example converting seconds to minutes and seconds, you probably read something like this:

```
int totalseconds = 72;
int minutes = totalseconds / 60; // == 1
int seconds = totalseconds % 60; // == 12
```

This is the same thing: the `minutes` are calculated as `totalseconds / 60`, which is an integral division that "rounds" to the lower integer for positive numbers, thus the result of `1`. The seconds left are calculated as the remainder of `72` and `60`.

You could also calculate the seconds like

```
int seconds = totalseconds - (minutes * 60)
```

Comment: thanks, I get that, I just wanted to learn why a%b returns a when [b] is bigger than [a], so its a rule, anyway thanks again

Comment: It's not a rule - it is just because this is how maths works. If `a < b`, then `0 * b + a = a`. That's basic school math... :-)

Comment: thanks for making me feel bad about my math knowledge :D just joking, but its obvious thinking by integers is not something i used to :)

Answer (score 0):

`a mod b` is the remainder of a `a / b`, therefore if `a < b AND a > -b` the remainder is always `a`.

The following rules are valid for C#, but might differ in other languages, refer to [Modulo operation page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for more information.

```
0 mod 3 = 0
1 mod 3 = 1
2 mod 3 = 2
3 mod 3 = 0
4 mod 3 = 1

-1 mod 3 = -1  // 2 in some languages
-2 mod 3 = -2  // 1 in some languages
-3 mod 3 = 0
-4 mod 3 = -1  // 2 in some languages

// if your language supports mod of floats
1.5 mod 3 = 1.5
5.5 mod 3 = 2.5
-1.5 mod 3 = -1.5  // 1.5 in some languages
-5.5 mod 3 = -2.5  // 0.5 in some languages
```